# Piles of Poker Chips

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I arrange $n$ identical poker chips into a series of piles $s=(p_1, p_2, \dots, p_m)$, with $\sum_{i=1}^{m}p_i = n$.

- How many $s$ exist for a given $n$? Or if $s \in S$: What is $|S_{n}|$?
- How do I enumerate $S_{n}$?

Examples:

- $S_{1} = \{(1)\} \rightarrow |S_{1}| = 1$
- $S_{2} = \{(1, 1), (2)\} \rightarrow |S_{2}| = 2$
- $S_{3} = \{(1, 1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3)\} \rightarrow |S_{3}| = 4$
- $S_{4} = \{(1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2), (2, 2), (1,3), (3, 1), (4)\} \rightarrow |S_{3}| = 8$

Comment: It may be helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: thank you. I do think composition is the keyword I was looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are ordered partitions, better known as compositions. The number of compositions of $n$ into $m$ parts enumerates to $\binom{n-1}{m-1}$ & the total number of compositions of $n$ is easily seen to be powers of $2$. Using the binomial theorem.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mid S_n \mid =\sum_{m=1}^{n} \binom{n-1}{m-1} =2^{n-1}. 
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

We want to count the number of ways to write $n$ as an ordered sum of positive integers. Note that choosing such an ordered sum is equivalent to choosing to put a $+$ sign or a comma in each of the $n-1$ boxes in the symbol
$$
\underbrace{(1\square1\square\dots\square1\square1)}_{n \,\text{ones}}
$$
How many ways are there to do this task?